# Get the updated APK version through C# Web Service and install it

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, web-services, apk

**Environment:**

Portal : ASP.NET with MySQL

Web Service: ASP.NET Web Service

**Requirement:**

1. Admin will upload the updated version of APK through my web
   application
2. Tablet will invoke the web service method to fiind the latest APK
   version
3. If latest APK found,
           Tablet should install the latest APK and proceed further
   Else
       Proceed.

For the above requirement I'm having 2 solutions.

**Solution1:**
- Store the uploaded APK in to byte in database
- Send the encoded(base64) byte to Tablet
- Table will decode the byte and convert in to .apk file

**Solution2:**
- Save the uploaded file in to drive
- Send the file URL(eg., http:///service/apkfile) to Tablet to download the APK

I think solution1 is perfect and trying to implement but we are getting 'Parsing Error' while converting byte in to .apk file in Tablet side. Becuase C# base64 having the range 0-255 but the other end Andoid App Base64 is having the range is -127 to 128.
So that I'm getting the error message.

Now, I need the answer for the following Qs.
1. Which solutions is perfect or I need to go ahead with something better?
2. If Solution1 is okay, then How to rectify the issue?

Comment: I would make use of the server file system for storing the APKs and just store file system paths in your database. Signedness of your bytes shouldn't be a problem. I believe you're doing something wrong in your decoding step or maybe your server does not print the Base64 string correctly. You could also just let your server deliver the APK in binary and leave out the Base64 encoding step. Don't forget to set the correct mime type.

Comment: @NobuGames The reason for moving database is more secure and reliable(I think), over the server file system. In Server file system could be possible to delete the file or corrupt the file.

Comment: You should see your file system as a very optimized high performance database for files. Using a database for storing files only adds an additional layer of complexity and occupies valuable server resources over the duration of the download. I agree that using a database makes it possible to have everything in one place. That can make backups easier. But saying that files in the file system can get deleted or corrupted is a moot point. Don't forget that your database is also stored in the file system and may get corrupted, too. Accidental APK file deletion can be dealt with proper permissions.

Comment: Thanks @NobuGames for your valid points to implement the solution2

Answer (score 1):

My Android Developer was done the mistake in Solution1. We have corrected the mistake and now it's working fine.

Mistake: He has missed the '/' at end of the installation path.

Also, Please ensure that the following points while installing the latest APK.

1. Min SDK Version should be same: Existing installed APK version should be same as updated APK version
2. Signed Key should be same for both APK (Existing and New)
3. No need to worry about the encoding and decoding
4. We've to allow the Non-Marketable apps to install (Menu >Settings >Applications >Enable the Unknown sources)